# How to get shell expansion on scala sys.process invocations

Tags: scala, process, expansion

Consider a simple attempt at shell expansion:

**Simple/direct approach** :

```
scala> ("/bin/ls /tmp/*" run BasicIO(false, sb, None)).exitValue
ls: /tmp/*: No such file or directory
res18: Int = 1
```

I have tried a number of combinations of ProcessIO, BasicIO, Process, etc and can not figure out how to get shell expansion to work.

**bash -c** :

```
scala> ("bash -c \"/bin/ls /tmp/*\"" run BasicIO(false, sb, None)).exitValue
/tmp/*": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/tmp/*": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
res19: Int = 2
```

**Pipe to bash -s** :

```
scala> ("echo \"/bin/ls /tmp/*\" | bash -s") run BasicIO(false, sb, None)).exitValue
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but ')' found.
       ("echo \"/bin/ls /tmp/*\" | bash -s") run BasicIO(false, sb, None)).exitValue
```

btw that last one in shell looks like the following (and works):

```
21:28:32/dstat $echo "/bin/ls /tmp/*" | bash -s

/tmp/OSL_PIPE_501_SingleOfficeIPC_a974a3af70d46eaeed927022833718b7
/tmp/oobelib.log
/tmp/spark-steve-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1.pid
/tmp/spark-steve-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1.pid
/tmp/KSOutOfProcessFetcher.501.qQkpPp2uZLdVc5pukHmfJMR4bkM=:
```

Shell escaping would also be of interest to understand wrt scala Process classes: an example including both expansion and escaping would be optimal.

**UPDATE**  I found this JIRA - it may be relevant. I hope not - that means there were little/no hope for the functionality described here..

*sys.process._ is so restrictive in what it can accept that is not usable*  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7027

**Another update**  I found an old email thread involving the esteemed ***Daniel Sobral*** who mentions:

> Because the quotes are not delimiting the parameter passed to bash -- 
>   it is Scala who decides how the arguments break up, and it simply 
>   splits on spaces, without any quotation facility. If you try the 
>   following, instead, it will work:
>
> Seq("bash", "-c", "ls *.scala").!

It is looking ever more grim for a "fire and forget" version of running a shell command.  I yearn for the **ruby**

```
 %x{whatever shell string you want goes here}
```

e.g.

> echo 'print %x{ls -lrtad /etc/* 2>&1}' | ruby

Which most satisfyingly returns:

```
-r--r--r--   1 root   wheel          69836 May 28  2013 /etc/php.ini.default-

5.2-previous~orig
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel             30 Oct 22  2013 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel            102 Nov  5  2013 /etc/hostconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel           1286 Nov  5  2013 /etc/my.cnf
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel           4161 Dec 18  2013 /etc/sshd_config~previous
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel            199 Feb  7  2014 /etc/shells
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel              0 Sep  9  2014 /etc/xtab
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel           1316 Sep  9  2014 /etc/ttys
  .. etc
```

but looks like that were *not happening* with Scala..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear you took my answer the wrong way. *Ruby is doing the same thing*, and I know this without looking at their code because what Java (and, by extension, Scala) presents as API is a direct translation of the Unix API.

It is *shell* that does shell expansions, and while it's perfectly possible for any other software to emulate them, it would be a losing game. Wildcards are often provided, but they are a small part of shell expansion.

My answer has everything you need, but let me expand on that:

```
import scala.sys.process._
implicit class RubyX(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def x(args: Any*): ProcessBuilder = {
    val strings = sc.parts.iterator
    val expressions = args.iterator
    var buf = new StringBuffer(strings.next)
    while(strings.hasNext) {
      buf append expressions.next
      buf append strings.next
    }
    Process(Seq("bash", "-c", buf.toString))
  }
}
```

then you can do

```
x"ls *.scala".!
```

I returned a ProcessBuilder, so you can pick whatever is the best form of execution for you, such as `!` above that returns the exit code and echoes everything else to stdout.

Comment: Oh I think now the important point is we need only *three* pieces to the Process(.) call. Given the entire command line is ONE of the three pieces - that works just fine.  Yes I had incorrectly gleaned that *every* piece of the command line needed to be a different member of the Process call.

Comment: Still missing something here:  scala> Process(Seq("bash","-C","ls /tmp/*")).!!
bash: ls /tmp/*: No such file or directory

Comment: @javadba Lowercase `-c`.

Comment: ah man.. wish you had noticed this earlier. just spent two hours trying to convert java.lang.Process code (and associated stream readers/writers) to scala.  but this works fine - and MUCH simpler. so in the end all good..